# In gradle, how to copy a subset of compiled test classes

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I tried taking a portion of the compiled test classes of a Gradle project, and put them in a jar file (to create a test case). What happened was, only those classes got compiled out of all test classes. Any idea how to do it right?

Here's my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

task testSampleJar(type: Zip) {
    archiveName "sample.jar"
    from compileTestJava {
        include "org/example/samples/**"
    }
}

test {
    dependsOn(testSampleJar)
}
```

So what seems to be happening is that by just defining the `testSampleJar` task, the `compileTestJava` task gets modified to only compile under org.example.samples package. My intent was to use the outputs of `compileTestJava` and pick something out of them them.

Thanks,
Uri

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured it out, so the two possible solutions are:

```
//a global filter
task testSampleJar(type: Zip) {
    archiveName "sample.jar"
    from compileTestJava
    include "org/example/samples/**"
}
```

Or

```
//Child specification - notice the parentheses around compileTestJava
task testSampleJar(type: Zip) {
    archiveName "sample.jar"
    from (compileTestJava) {
        include "org/example/samples/**"
    }
}
```

I guess the original code was defining compileTestJava instead of using its output, but I don't have a full grasp of Groovy/Gradle DSL to be certain.